# ASP.NET Set color style dynamically using inline coding in aspx

Tags: asp.net, fonts, eval, inline-code

I need to the set the font color dynamically. I can access the color value in my ASPX directly using :

```
<%# Eval("FontColor", true) %>
```

However, I am not able to figure out as to how I should assign it to the color attribute or style attribute. I tried the following ways but none of them worked out.

First :

```
<font style="line-height: 10px; font-size: 12px;" color="<%# Eval("FontColor", true) %>">ABC</font>
```

Second :

```
<font style="line-height: 10px; font-size: 12px; color: <%# Eval("FontColor", true) %>;">ABC</font>
```

Comment: why are you using `true` as second argument in `Eval`?

Comment: It's just to encode the value. Setting it as true would encode the value.

Comment: Ohk..You are right..The above Eval method is coming up from a different class of Kentico. If I use the DataBinder class, the expression to fetch the value would turn up as : <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 'FontColor').ToString() %>

Comment: I don't have a trouble fetching the value. The concern here is how can I use this fetched value to modify the color ? I am getting the error as 'Too many characters in character literal'.